# How to open custom chrome tabs in nativescripts angular

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hello there am try to open custom chrome tab using below code in NativeScripts(5.3.1).

```
  var color = require("color");
  var app = require("application");
  var url = '';      
  var builder = new android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent.Builder();     
  builder.setToolbarColor(new color.Color("#ff4081").android);
  builder.setShowTitle(true);
  var customTabsIntent = builder.build();
  customTabsIntent.launchUrl(app.android.startActivity, android.net.Uri.parse(url));
```

and i added implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.2.0' in app-resources->Android->app.gradle

getting error like this Property 'customtabs' does not exist on type 'typeof support'.
help me out this.

Comment: It's possible that your app was not fully complied, try a clean build. Moreover we already have [nativescript-advanced-webview](https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-advanced-webview) plugin which supports Chrome Custom Tabs.

Comment: i am also try with advanced-webview it's working fine but how to call back programmatically when reach particular url?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get what you mean, are you asking for a interceptor so you can prevent user from visiting particular links?

Comment: i am try to open paypal window for payments after successful transaction, i am try to close browser but i'm not find any call back functions how to back to our application programmatically?

Comment: The plugin do not support such callbacks, user will have to manually close the page. If you are interested, you may take a fork and add the feature Or directly use the native apis in your project.